# What is the best way to list all the background images used on a webpage?

Tags: php, css, background-image

I'm looking at measuring page load performance and ideally would like to create an array in php of all background images a webpage is using to factor these into how long the the page takes to load.

The code ideally would scan all css files called on a page, there may be more than one and within these css files there many be many classes and some of the classes with background images might relate to other pages on the site. So I only want to grab the urls for background images in classes which are used on the initial page I am testing.

Any pointers on how you would achieve this in PHP would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need a file, or can you use the resources tab on FireBug or Chrome Developer Tools to show you load?

Comment: I want to run it as a cron job and save the results to a database.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is:

1. Use file_get_contents() to return the raw HTML of the rendered php scripts.
2. Parse out all of the  to load all of my stylesheets into an array.
3. Iterate through that array loading its contents and parsing for url() to return an array of background images.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Would a JavaScript version be acceptable for you? I personally would think it is easier to select all elements with jquery and iterate through them.

UPDATE

Sorry for the long wait. In JavaScript (using jQuery) I would do it something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body *').each(function() {
    var cssbg = $(this).css('background-image');

    alert(cssbg);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah it would be interesting to see how this could be done in JavaScript.

Comment: I am on my mobile just now, so I can't really write the code just now. I will be able to post it in the morning.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to add that.